# Cardinality of equivalence classes

Tags: cardinals

The relation ~ is defined on P(N): A~B if |A| = |B|.

I need to prove that the cardinality of the equivalence classes is countable.

Any ideas??

Comment: I think that must use the continous hypotesis...

Comment: Continuum hypothesis is definitely not required here.  If $A\subset \mathbb{N}$ is infinite, then it is countably-infinite.  The only remaining ones are the finite sets, so define a function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})/\sim$ by sending $0$ to $[\mathbb{N}]$, and $n$ to $[\{1,\ldots, n-1\}]$ for $n\geq 1$.

Comment: Is there any more context? What is $P(N)$ here?

Comment: @Hayden I think I got it. Shouldn't the function be defined n to [(1,..,n}]?

Comment: In that case, you'd miss $[\emptyset]$, which was intended to be the image of $1$ (a notation like $\{1,\ldots, n-1\}$ is usually meant to denote the empty set when $n-1 < 1$).

Comment: I see it now, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The cardinalities of the subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ are the natural numbers themselves and $\aleph_0$ ($=|\mathbb{N}|$), so this amounts to proving that the set $\mathbb{N} \cup \{ \aleph_0 \}$ is countable.